mamba repoquery whoneeds fails to find installed package, but mamba repoquery depends finds it
When I run mamba list I can see the package libgoogle-cloud is listed. When I run mamba repoquery whoneeds libgoogle-cloud I get a message stating it cannot be found:
No entries matching "libgoogle-cloud" found
libgoogle-cloud may not be installed. Try giving a channel with '-c,--channel' option for remote repoquery

When I reverse the command: mamba repoquery depends libgoogle-cloud, it does return results. Why would depends be able to find it without the channel and not whoneeds?
(When I run mamba repoquery whoneeds -c conda-forge libgoogle-cloud it does return results, but that's besides the point.)
